# Procedimiento almacenado no devuelve valores

Tags: javascript, mysql, nodejs, typescript, stored-procedure

soy algo nuevo en cuanto a los procedimientos almacenados en node :C

### Presentación del problema.

Resulta que al ejecutar un procedimiento almacenado que me selecciona la contraseña de un usuario si el correo coincide no me devuelve los resultados de la consulta, en cambio, me devuelve lo siguiente:

```
[
  [
    [ [TextRow] ],
    ResultSetHeader {
      fieldCount: 0,
      affectedRows: 0,
      insertId: 0,
      info: '',
      serverStatus: 2,
      warningStatus: 0
    }
  ],
  [ [ [ColumnDefinition] ], undefined ]
]
```

### Anotaciones.

La verdad no comprendo porqué sucede esto, si HASTA EN LA CONSOLA SI FUNCIONA, si yo lo ejecuto en la consola me devuelve lo siguiente:

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| pass                                                         |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| $2b$10$1YFPycHGaAl51JTQivOoEeFNiv8NKGD225VeqR3Y/4wOvzWNvyJx. |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.011 sec)
```

Lo cual si está bien, ya que eso es lo que me debe de devolver. Otro dato curioso es que he ejecutado otro procedimiento con node, que se trata de insertar unos datos, y ese procedimiento si funciona de lujo.

La verdad he investigado bastante antes de llegar hasta aquí, pero resulta que no he encontrado ninguna solución a este problema.

### Recursos:

Estoy utilizando typescript con mysql2 y sus promesas, este es mi archivo de conexión donde a la vez tengo una función para conectarme a la DB.

```
import {PoolConnection, createPool, Pool} from 'mysql2/promise';
import {database} from './config';
const pool: Pool = createPool(database);

export function connect(): Promise<PoolConnection> {
  return new Promise(async (resolved, reject) => {
    try {
      const connection: PoolConnection = await pool.getConnection();
      resolved(connection);
    } catch (e) {
      reject(e);
    }
  });
}
```

Por último, esta es la función que me está causando problemas:

```
import {PoolConnection} from 'mysql2/promise';
import {connect} from '../../database';
import {comparePass} from '../../helpers/helperFunctions';

export function validLoginUser(mail: string, pass: string) {
  return new Promise<void>(async (resolved, reject) => {
    try {
      const conn: PoolConnection = await connect();
      const query: any = await conn.query(`CALL searchUserLogin(?)`, [mail]);
      console.log(query);
      resolved();
      // if (hash.length === 0) {
      //   resolved(false);
      //   return;
      // }
      // const isValid: boolean = await comparePass(hash, pass);
      // if(isValid){

      // }
      // resolved(isValid);
    } catch (e) {
      reject(e);
    }
  });
}
```

PD: Lo que está comentado no le presten atención, eso es algo que estaba haciendo pero pues no he podido hacer básicamente porque la query no me devuelve lo que requiero.

Mi procedimiento almacenado es el siguiente:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `searchUserLogin`(
    IN `mail_IN` VARCHAR(55)
)
LANGUAGE SQL
NOT DETERMINISTIC
READS SQL DATA
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
COMMENT ''
BEGIN
    SELECT pass FROM users
    WHERE mail = mail_IN;
END
```

Y para finalizar mi tabla de usuarios es la siguiente:

```
+----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| userID   | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| userName | varchar(55)      | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| mail     | varchar(55)      | NO   | UNI | 0       |                |
| pass     | varchar(150)     | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| avatar   | varchar(8)       | NO   |     | n-1     |                |
+----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Desde ya muchas gracias al alma caritativa que me pueda ayudar :D

Comment: ¿Si ejecutas tu PA solamente dentro de tu base mysql si funciona?

Comment: @BetaM, así es, como dije en la pregunta, ya lo he ejecutado varias veces y funciona de lujo, es con node el problema :C

Answer (score 0):

Después de investigar en bastantes sitios, logré encontrar uno en github: https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2/issues/1196, aquí explican que para poder acceder al contenido que devuelve el procedimiento almacenado hay que hacer dos destructuring de la respuesta, de manera que queda así:

```
const [[query]]: any = await conn.query('CALL `searchUserLogin`(?)', [mail]);
```